# How can I be certain of display's refresh rate?

Tags: windows-xp, display, refresh-rate

There is an experiment that requires a 100Hz refresh rate, so we bought a 144Hz capable monitor and created a custom resolution that runs at 100Hz.

The experimenter felt something was wrong with the refresh rate, and using the monitor's buttons and on-screen menu, saw it was in fact reporting a 60Hz rate.

However, Windows and Nvidia's control panel say it's 100Hz. There are many peculiarities better suited for another question, but here I want to ask how can I determine the actual refresh rate?

Unfortunately this experiment is stuck on Windows XP. The video card is a GeForce 9400. The cable is a Mini-DP to Dual-link DVI. This is because it's running in BootCamp on an old [Mac Mini (Early 2009)](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-2-duo-2.0-early-2009-nvidia-specs.html)...though I hope the problem isn't related to this odd HW setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up downloading [MPC-HC](http://mpc-hc.org/), and changing the renderer to `VMR9`, or any DXVA renderer, in **Playback** > **Options**.

Then I could play a video and use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> to see the refresh rate:
[image: MPC-HC DXVA Stats]

Ultimately saw that the system was practically non-interactive when using the GPU, and I assume there's something wrong with the old hardware/bootcamp/depreciated OS situation.

Answer (score 1):

The refresh rate reported by the monitor itself should be accurate.  Also if you're using a VGA connector, you can use an oscilloscope to probe the vsync line to see if the video card is indeed syncing at 100hz.  Also pin 8 on a dvi connector carries the analog vsync signal as well.  Take a look at this also: 
https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/172075-Get-VSYNC-from-DVI-on-NVIDIA-card

Comment: Thanks, that's clever. Don't think I've seen an oscilloscope, thoguh I'd love to play around with it for this. But I'm more software, less soldering iron. Anyway +1 for novelty.